In B4A, external folder storage
My codes should be correct, but I could not get the correct resourse to edit my Manifest file to allow SAVE permission.
Private Sub btn_SAVE_Click      
  Dim const FILENAME As String = "MyTextFile.txt"   
  Dim const FOLDER_NAME As String = "MyFolder"      
  Dim FolderPath As String  
  FolderPath = File.Combine(File.DirRootExternal,FOLDER_NAME)       

  Dim textToSave As String  
  textToSave=txtbox_TEXT01.Text 
  If File.Exists(FolderPath, FILENAME) = False Then          
    File.MakeDir(File.DirRootExternal, FOLDER_NAME)
  End If 

  File.WriteString(FolderPath,FILENAME,textToSave)  
  'Dim Out As OutputStream  
  'Out = File.OpenOutput(FolderPath, FILENAME,False)     
  'Out.WriteBytes(textToSave.GetBytes("UTF8"),0,0)  
  'Out.Close    
   ToastMessageShow("File saved OK!", True) 
End Sub

My APP crashed and quitted, after clicking SAVE button.

Please format your code correctly inside the triple-backtick marks.  You should tag the language.  Is this Visual Basic.NET?  Is if VBA?  Where did it crash?  How did you try to add SAVE permission?

At least make an effort to format your code so that it's readable. I've fixed it for you this time, but we shouldn't have to do it in the future. You can get formatting help by clicking the ? toolbar button in the editor toolbar.

Thanks for your advice. My question is not clear maybe, I shall format the codes and revise the question. Thanks for your correction for me.
